# Graphviz: aligning a graph wrt its label

Tags: alignment, graphviz, presentation

By default, Graphviz centers the graph relatively to its caption (label):

```
graph {
    label="lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit"
    A -- B
}
```

[image: A simple graph]

How can I align the graph to the left, i.e., make A, B and the initial of "lorem" vertically aligned?
The attributes `labeljust` and `labelloc` have other purposes, and I cannot see anything in the [reference](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html) to achieve this result.

Comment: It makes sense. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

(it helps it include your source as text, not png)
No direct way, but (if needed) use invisible nodes and/or node **width** to get the graph wide enough to meet your needs.  Then use the **labeljust** attribute to to justify the label to the left (or right) of the entire graph.

```
graph {
  //  does not seem to work  size="8!"
  label="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvblahblah" labeljust=r
  {rank=same a  node[style=invis width="2."] x1 x2 edge[style=invis] x1--a--x2}
  a--b
}
```

giving:
[image]

Comment: Nice workaround, thanks. Concerning `size="8!"`, it seems to work with `layout=neato`, but this is not the layout I need.